# Render a textured rectangle with PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, glut

I'm working on a project using PyOpenGL, and I'm currently attempting to get OpenGL to render a kind of splash screen. My decided solution to this is to draw a textured 2D rectangle. Unfortunately, it appears that no matter what I do, nothing is ever drawn, I just get a black screen (So I guess something is drawn, otherwise it would be a transparent window, but it's definitely not what I want). Here is the pertinent code for my class:

```
class ClassThing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Splash = True
        glutInit(sys.argv)

    def TexFromPNG(self, filename):
        img = Image.open(filename)
        img_data = numpy.array(list(img.getdata()), numpy.uint8)

        texture = glGenTextures(1)
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, img.size[0], img.size[1], 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_data)
        return texture

    def run(self):
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA)

        glutInitWindowSize(256,224)
        self.window = glutCreateWindow("GL")
        glutDisplayFunc(self.draw)

        glClearColor(0,0,0,0)
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glEnable(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

        self.MainTex = glGenTextures(1)
        self.SplashTex = self.TexFromPNG("Resources/Splash.png")

        glutMainLoop()

    def draw(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        glLoadIdentity()
        if self.Splash:
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.SplashTex)
        else:
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.MainTex)

        glTexParameter(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexParameter(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER)
        Varray = numpy.array([[0,0],[0,256],[224,256],[224,0]],numpy.uint16)
        glVertexPointer(2,GL_SHORT,0,Varray)
        indices = [0,1,2,3]
        glDrawElements(GL_QUADS,1,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,indices)

        glFlush()
thing = ClassThing()
thing.run()
```

As I said, just that nets me with a totally black screen. It feels like I may be missing some kind of initialization or enabling, but I don't know what else I would need to enable.

As an aside, apparently glVertexPointer is deprecated, how would I run glDrawElements without it? Is there some kind of vertex generation you can do similar to texture generation or what?

Answer (score 4):

Could it be because you called `glGenTextures(1)` twice? You assigned it to texture in TexFromPNG and assigned it to self.MainTex in run.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply texture coordinates as well, otherwise OpenGL doesn't know how to map the texture to your quad — you also could use automatic texture coordinate generation, but in your case just specifying coordinates is simpler. In addition you also need to specify viewport and projection

```
class ClassThing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Splash = True

    def TexFromPNG(self, filename):
        img = Image.open(filename)
        img_data = numpy.array(list(img.getdata()), numpy.uint8)

        texture = glGenTextures(1)
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)

        # Texture parameters are part of the texture object, so you need to 
        # specify them only once for a given texture object.
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, img.size[0], img.size[1], 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_data)
        return texture

    def run(self):
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA)

        glutInitWindowSize(256,224)
        self.window = glutCreateWindow("GL")
        glutReshapeFunc(self.reshape)
        glutDisplayFunc(self.draw)

        self.MainTex = glGenTextures(1)
        self.SplashTex = self.TexFromPNG("Resources/Splash.png")

        glutMainLoop()

    def reshape(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        glutPostRedisplay();

    def draw(self):
        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)

        glClearDepth(1) # just for completeness
        glClearColor(0,0,0,0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glOrtho(0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1)

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity()

        if self.Splash:
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.SplashTex)
        else:
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.MainTex)

        # it's a good idea to enable state right before you need it
        # there's no such thing like global state intialization in
        # OpenGL
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        # vertex arrays must be enabled using glEnableClientState
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)

        Varray = numpy.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0]],numpy.float)
        glVertexPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,0,Varray)
        glTexCoordPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,0,Varray)
        indices = [0,1,2,3]
        glDrawElements(GL_QUADS,1,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,indices)

        # This implies a glFinish, which includes a glFlush
        glutSwapBuffers() 

# GLUT initialization in program global, so initialize it on
# the process level. It might be 
glutInit(sys.argv)

thing = ClassThing()
thing.run()
```

Comment: Hmm, no dice. I made those changes and I still get the same black screen. However, after doing a little more reading, it appears this whole method is basically deprecated in favor of using VBOs with shaders.