# How to load an *.obj file and apply a texture to it?

Tags: python, opengl, 3d, pyopengl

How can I load an *.obj 3d model in Python and apply a texture to it? I managed to load, view and apply textures to simple blocks and walls, but it seems impossible to apply a texture to a 3d model. How can I do that in Python?

I'm using PyOpenGL and I'm not allowed to use PyGame by my teacher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might want to check out ASSIMP, it has python bindings:  https://github.com/assimp/assimp

also, if you feel like writing your own .obj loader (it is a pretty simple format) check out this tutorial:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Load_OBJ

Comment: Using enters in a comment seems not possible, so please click this link: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8F6597268E454CF3!1385&authkey=!AA_rpoahhKLkxIM&ithint=file%2c.txt

Comment: you might be misreading the windows bitmap (.bmp) file... there is a header in there.  try using stb_image.h to load the image to rule that out: https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h

Comment: oops, sorry forgot you were using python.  actually, now that i look at your codes you are using glGenTexures incorrectly... it's not the return value that refers to the texture object, but rather the second (out parameter) argument.  i don't even know how that is compiling, glGenTextures should always take two arguments.

Comment: For example I use two models, each with one textures.
    glGenTextures(2, t)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t[0]) gives an error, but also
    glGenTextures(1, t)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t) gives an error.
    And although the docs agree with you all examples on internet use the return value.

Comment: hmm, you are right does this example help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907613/render-a-textured-rectangle-with-pyopengl

Comment: Thanks racarate, that example helped me a great deal. Everything works now fine, but there is one thing that still is a bit strange: the camera is flipped. I mean, how can I flip my display horizontally? How can I draw things on the left side of my screen draw at the right side?

Comment: I used the wrong word, how can I mirror my screen horizontally?

Comment: i don't know offhand, when i've built projection matrices manually ive  used a negative z-scale value to mirror objects... but i think you are working at a higher level of abstraction here

Comment: The negative z-scale didn't work, but After some experimenting using a negative x-scale before calling gluPerspective did work. Everything works now fine.